Tables are only available through PGAdmin
I am using PostgreSQL for an API. This is my current setup:

Here is what I did to make the PostgreSQL container and table
docker pull postgres:latest  
docker volume create postgres-volume  
docker run --name \<my name\> --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=\<my password\> --volume postgres- volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data --publish 5432:5432 --detach postgres

Then I went into PGadmin and connected to this PostgreSQL server using localhost, port 5432 and the user postgres. I then made a table in this database postgres which is in this server.
Using Psycopg2 (Python)
Using the snippet below, I am able to connect to the server but it does not show any tables:
try: 
      conn = psycopg2.connect(host = 'localhost', database= 'postgres', user = 'postgres',password='root',cursor_factory=RealDictCursor ) 
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      print("Database connection successful")

      cursor.execute("select relname from pg_class where relkind='r' and relname !~'^(pg_|sql_)';")
        print(cursor.fetchall())
    break
except Exception as error:
    print("Database connection failed")
    print("Error: ", error)

I get:

Database connection successful
[]

The table is not there!
Using psql in the container
$ docker exec -it <container name> bash
$ \c <Database name>
$ \dt

The table I made is not there!

What is causing this?
I made the container in PGadmin. I can see and connect to the database but the Table is not there. I checked common issues such as the table not being public etc. but I am still unsure as to what might be causing this? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.


This I made the container in PGadmin. does not make sense.  2) Not seeing the table comes down to either a) You did not commit after creating the table in pgAdmin and it did not persist. b) You have more then one instance of Postgres running and you are connecting to a different one in each case.


@AdrianKlaver thank you for your input. I deleted my env and restarted it and everything runs now EXCEPT when connecting to the server I use host.docker.internal instead of localhost. I think the issue was that there may have been multiple instances connected on port 5432.
